# Ошибка присваивания r-value

Tags: c++

Почему не компилируется?

```
int x=0;
(x++)=3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не компилируется потому что выражение `x++` возвращает r-value тип, т.е. то, что может использоваться только справа от `=`.

Comment: А почему тогда это работает?
`int* p=new int;
 *p++ *=2.54;`

Comment: у постфиксного плюса больше приоритет ??? ясно